# setting nodes timer in swift scene

Tags: swift, timer, sprite-kit, nodes, nstimer

I have a scene that contain a class name ballNode() which declare ball and its properties. now, I want that every defined second a ball will spawn the frame. I read about how to do it and realise that I need to set a timer. so I read a tutorial and saw some videos about it. as I follow the tutorials I finally get this code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var tim = Timer()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -9.8)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self 


    tim = Timer.init(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(createSmallBall) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    let sceneBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame) 
    sceneBody.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = sceneBody

}

@objc func createSmallBall(){
    let smallBall = BallNode(radius: 30)
    smallBall.position.x = 100
    smallBall.position.y = 200
    self.addChild(smallBall)
}
```

Although I follow the instructions (and adjust it to swift 4 - the selectors issue) I still don't see any ball on my frame.

I looking for the problem for 2 hours and cant find it (the createSmallBall is working - I checked this up by setting it inside touchesbegin()).

can someone found what an I doing wrong?

Comment: you really should consider using the Spritekit timing functionality through the update func. that aside try setting smallBall.zPosition =1 and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

after lot of reading, I understood that the best way to use timers on `spriteKit` is via `SKAction`. as I understood, Timers are useless in spriteKit because they ignore nodes and scenes (if Im not wrong they ignore   the view's pause method).
so, there are only two ways left to set a timer: use the `update(currentTime)` function or use the better and the common way - `SKAction`.
as I understood, SKAction is more simple and much more easier to do it, the main function/method used is the `sequence` one.

here how it should be done in swift:

```
func spawnBalls() {
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)
    let action = SKAction.run {
        //your code here
    }
    run(SKAction.repeatForever((SKAction.sequence([wait, action]))))
}
```

and here is explanation line by line:

```
let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)
```

**.wait(forDuration:_)** - setting a let that contain time. basically used to set the time between each action. the time interval is by seconds.

```
let action = SKAction.run{ //code here }
```

**.run** - setting the action itself, inside the curly brackets should be the action code (move, fade, rotate, animate etc). the action is executed **only** after you tell a node to run it.

```
run(SKAction.repeatForever((SKAction.sequence([wait, action]))))
```

in this line what I actually did was to run action. the use of  `repeatForver()` says that I want my action to run forever (regularly). but the most interesting part in this line is the `sequence([])` - that allow to chain together a sequence of action that performed in order (one at time), as I get it its like insert my `SKAction` vars into an array of action the first action executed then the second and so on. the line in my code says that first the wait var will execute (= wait 3 seconds) and then the action var. because I set it as repeatforever - it will execute repeatedly (respectively if I delete this the code will be execute only once).

by using SKAction you can also group together some action - **.group**: its advantage is that you can run a group of action that will run **synchronously**.

[here is](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction) apple doc for the SKAction.

hope this helps those who need it.